# Show Settings Flyout using a button

Tags: javascript, microsoft-metro

My Settings Flyout has 3 categories (Preferences, Help and About)

Is there a way to show for example the Help flyout directly using a button which is located in the appbar?

To show the Settings Flyout I'm using the following:

```
Windows.UI.ApplicationSettings.SettingsPane.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can programmatically show a SettingsFlyout using the [SettingsFlyout.showSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh770581.aspx) method.  The [WinJS ApplicationSettings SDK sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-settings-sample-1f762f49/sourcecode?fileId=50852&pathId=599371597) has an example usage in Scenario 4:

```
document.getElementById("scenario4Show").addEventListener("click", scenario4ShowSettingsFlyout, false); 

function scenario4ShowSettingsFlyout() { 
        WinJS.UI.SettingsFlyout.showSettings("defaults", "/html/4-SettingsFlyout-Settings.html"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No there's no direct way to show an option from a settings flyout . you have to use the settings pane . Rather you can create your own Settings charm. One way to do is to opent the page you want to open programatically . Like in help or privacy statement redirect the user to the respective pages you have designed . But the default settings you cannot open. its not under our control